# Trying to get a user input to make a 2-D array multiplication table

Tags: c, arrays, nested, tabular

```
int main (void)
{
    int range, i, j;

    printf("Input size of multiplication table: ");
    scanf("%i", &range);

    int output[range][range];

    for (i = 0; i<=range; ++i)
    {
        for (j=0; j<=range; ++j)
        {
            output[i][j] = i * j;
            if(j!=range && output[i][j] != 0)
            {
                printf("%3i ", output[i][j]);
            }
            else if (j==range)
            {
                printf("%3i", output[i][j]);
            }
            else if (output[i][j] == 0)
            {
                printf("%3i "), i+2;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%3i", j + i - range);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

I am having it output:

```
0   1   2   3   4   0
5   1   2   3   4   5
10   2   4   6   8  10
15   3   6   9  12  15
20   4   8  12  16  20
25   5  10  15  20  25
```

and I need the 0 on the end to be a five and the first column to be 0,1,2,3,4,5 instead of 0,5,10,15,20,25.
If anyone could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: `printf("%3i "), i+2;` is wrong because data to format via `printf()` is missing, but there should be other problems.

Answer (score 2):

You have two primary problems, (1) you fail to validate your user input, and (2) your loop bounds are incorrect, e.g.

Any time you take user input, you must **validate** that you actually received what you expected and that any conversion required, was completed successfully. Failure to validate will lead to *Undefined Behavior* it invalid (or no) input is provide. (e.g. What if the user enters `foo` instead of `10`?) When using `scanf`, you must validate the **return** which provides the count of the number of conversions that successfully took place, e.g.

```
    printf ("Input size of multiplication table: ");
    if (scanf("%i", &range) != 1) { /* VALIDATE ALL USER INPUT */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

That is bare minimum. You can also check if the return is `EOF` to indicate the user canceled input with a <kbd>[Ctrl+D]</kbd> (or <kbd>[Ctrl+Z]</kbd> on windoze -- must be explicitly enabled on Win10).

Next, your loop bound are `for (i = 0; i < range; i++)` **not** `i <= range`, that invokes *Undefined Behavior* by attempting to access memory outside your array bounds. Simply fix the loop condition, e.g.

```
    for (i = 0; i< range; i++) {    /* fill multiplication table */
        for (j = 0; j< range; j++) {
            output[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);   /* i+1 * j+1 */
        }
    }
```

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int range, i, j;

    printf ("Input size of multiplication table: ");
    if (scanf("%i", &range) != 1) { /* VALIDATE ALL USER INPUT */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int output[range][range];       /* variable length array */

    for (i = 0; i< range; i++) {    /* fill multiplication table */
        for (j = 0; j< range; j++) {
            output[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);   /* i+1 * j+1 */
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i< range; i++) {    /* output table */
        for (j = 0; j< range; j++)
            printf (" %3d", output[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** the trivial parts of the table is omitted (e.g. `0 * anything`), and duplicated rows of `1 * anything` are also not shown. If you need to additional rows, you can add them back.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/multable
Input size of multiplication table: 10
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20
   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30
   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

---

**To Show the 1X Rows**

You simply update your print routine as follows:

```
    for (i = 0; i< range; i++) {    /* output table */
        if (!i) {
            printf ("    ");
            for (j = 0; j< range; j++)
                printf (" %3d", output[i][j]);
            putchar ('\n');
        }
        printf (" %3d", i + 1);
        for (j = 0; j< range; j++)
            printf (" %3d", output[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/multable1
Input size of multiplication table: 10
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
   1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
   2   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20
   3   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30
   4   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
   5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
   6   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
   7   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
   8   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
   9   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
  10  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution below. It's all about properly managing iterators (note the less-equal sign in the ranges and the subtraction of indexes by 1 in the assignment). You can do it very concisely by assigning to output inside the printf and using a ternary-if. (I also used dynamic allocation in order to comply with ISO standards.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int range, i, j;

    printf("Enter the size of the multiplication table:\n");
    scanf("%d", &range);

    int ** output = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * (long unsigned int) range);

    for(i = 0; i <= range; ++i)
    {
        output[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (long unsigned int) range);

        for(j = 0; j <= range; ++j)
            printf("%3d ", !i ? j : !j ? i : (output[i - 1][j - 1] = i * j));

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```